# refreshing google map

Tags: google-maps

how can I refresh googlemap using javascript ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use the clearOverlays function to clear all markers, if thats what you are asking for

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
map.clearOverlays();
```